# How to create dependencies in automake?

Tags: makefile, autoconf, automake

I have a Makefile.am file right now that looks like this:

```
lib_LIBRARIES = foo.a

foo_a_SOURCES = bar.F90 baz.F90
```

When compiled, bar.F90 gives bar.o. However, bar.F90 depends on several other Fortran files (cat.F90, dog.F90, pig.F90). I want to set up Automake to rebuild bar.o if the source of one of these dependencies change.

I've been reading the GNU manuals for automake/autoconf and was unable to find a solution to this. Thanks for reading.

Comment: If bar.F90 is a built source, you should list it in BUILT_SOURCES.  Search for _DEPENDENCIES in the automake info pages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Automake tracks most source-level dependencies automatically as described in [the Dependencies section](http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Dependencies.html) of [its manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/). If you already knew that and experimentation has shown that it isn't working you will likely have to override the `bar.o` target to add dependencies as described in [the Extending section](http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Extending.html).